# Multiple jQuery selector criteria on a single attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Is it possible to combine multiple jquery selectors on a single attribute? e.g. finding all links to PDF files that are in the "media/pdfs" directory.

Links with an href containing "media/pdfs"

```
$("a[href*='media/pdfs']")
```

Links to a PDF file

```
$("a[href$='.pdf']")
```

I'm hoping it's possible to combine somehow like below?

```
$("a[href*='media/pdfs/*.pdf']")
```

It'd be easily fixed with a regex but [the documentation on selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) doesn't say anything about that being possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just combine them as normal:

```
$("a[href*='media/pdfs'][href$='.pdf']")
```

Live Example:

```js
$("a[href*='media/pdfs'][href$='.pdf']").css("color", "green");
```

```html
<div><a href="media/pdfs/foo.pdf">Match</a></div>
<div><a href="media/pdfs/foo.jpg">Not a match</a></div>
<div><a href="foo.pdf">Not a match</a></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I didn't realise you could chain together selectors on the same property and make it meet both criteria. Confirmed as working. Thanks :)